# React return html based on condition

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have following code

```
function BookMaster()
{
const [BookDetails,setBookDetails] = useState({})

useEffect(()=> {
   -----here API call
   setBookDetails(res.data)
```

Here, BookDetails has a flag "IsAllowed"
And I want to return the HTML based on this Flag, something like follows

```
return (
    if({BookDetails.IsAllowed==1})
    {
      <div><Label>This book is allowed</Label>
    }
    else
    {
      <div><Label>This book is NOT allowed</Label>
    }
)
```

But this is not working as expected. Could you please share your thoughts?

Comment: "But this is not working as expected" - what exactly do you get? an error? or nothing? or what?

Comment: I would do something like this.  `return <div><Label>This book is {BookDetails.IsAllowed === 1 ? 'NOT ' : ''} allowed</Label></div>`

Comment: Also, if you know `IsAllowed` will be an int, always use a triple equals for comparison.

Comment: @sowam, it was showing an error in the debug.

Comment: @dmikester1 yes this is correct. I did the same. it worked too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:
`if({BookDetails.IsAllowed==1})` this code is wrong, it should be

```
if( BookDetails.IsAllowed==1 )
```

does it fix it?

Comment: yes, this helped. this for quickly getting back. will accept this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

In the if condition parenthesis are not allowed. Basically its a syntax error. try the below one

```
    return (
        <div>
          <Label>
            { BookDetails.IsAllowed === 1 
               ? 'This book is allowed'
               : 'This book is NOT allowed' }
         </Label> 
       </div>
        )
```

if you are not using locale and interested to add template literals, try below one

```
return (
    <div>
      <Label>
        {`This book is ${BookDetails.IsAllowed !== 1 ? 'NOT' : '' } allowed`}
     </Label> 
   </div>
    )
```

Comment: yes this also helps, thanks for your response.